# Load balancing using mod_cluster with httpd and Tomcat only?

Tags: tomcat, load-balancing, mod-cluster

Is it possible to design a load balancer using Apache Httpd with **mod_cluster** and Tomcat only (No JBossAS or JBossWeb)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading various articles I tried out myself and it's possible to build a load balancer using Apache Httpd, mod_cluster and Tomcat.

Following are the links which helped me a lot.

http://docs.jboss.org/mod_cluster/1.1.0/html/

http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/48086/0/page/2

http://community.jboss.org/thread/160494